# Github to launchpad sync

Tags: github, bazaar, launchpad

I am working on a open source project which uses bazaar for versioning and launchpad for repo. The project also has github repo but launchpad repo is primary. I am behind college proxy so i can't access ssh required to connect to launchpad to merge/push  changes. Is there a way, that i commit, push all changes on my github account, and they get reflected on my launchpad account too. Can I send merge requests too?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you overall idea , how to do that

create your project `test` in github and will be owned by organization name `Acc`.

then just push the `master` branch to `test`

Now fork the project and clone

Push all your local branches to your GitHub fork `git push -a origin`

And checkout that branch using `git checkout <branch_name>`. And then push to origin of that branch.

> Launchpad is a project-centric environment, so you will most likely have a GitHub organization that owns the ‘main’ repository and encourage all members and newcomers to fork from that.

within fork developer can able to work on that, usually when about to issue a pull request – GitHub’s version of a merge proposal, pull down changes from the `upstream` organization master into their master. Since this will happen relatively often it is easiest to add an additional ‘`remote`’ target for it:

```
git remote add acc `http://github.com/acc/test.git`
```